"cannot execute: required file not found" When trying to execute binary
I'm new to assembly. I'm currently following this ARM assembly tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKtWsuuJEDs&list=PLn_It163He32Ujm-l_czgEBhbJjOUgFhg&index=1
I wrote the exact same thing as in the tutorial:
.global _start
.section .text
_start:
        mov r0, #42
        mov r7, #1
        swi 0

and I used the exact same commands to generate the object file, then the executable:
arm-linux-gnueabi-as hello.s -o hello.o and arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.o -o hello -nostdlib
Still, I get the message -bash: ./hello: cannot execute: required file not found when running ./hello.
I made sure every command and every line I typed was the same as in the tutorial though... I'm working on the Raspberry pi 400 over SSH with the latest Raspberry Pi OS lite 64 bits. Could someone help me with this please ?

Does -static help?  But linking with GCC should use the right path for /lib/ld.so for a dynamic executable even if it's not ld's default, so that should only matter if you don't have the 32-bit multiarch support installed.  (You have a 64-bit OS but you're making a 32-bit ARM binary, for AArch32 state not AArch64.)  What does file hello say?

What happens if you change your 'r's to 'x's and your 1 to 93 and your sw0 to svc? As Peter noted you are writing 32-bit arm assembly on a 64-bit OS. What does lscpu tell you? You should see your processor type as Cortex-A72. Why not make the changes and compile with as -mcpu=cortex-a72 -o hello.o hello.s and then ld -o hello hello.o? Then after you run your program you can do echo $? and see 42.

What does ldd ./hello output?

Before spending a lot of time getting this to work, are you sure it's actually your goal to learn 32-bit ARM assembly when you have a 64-bit ARM64 device?  Are you aiming to program for very low-end embedded devices (toaster controllers, etc) in the long term, or something like that?  I think a lot of people decide "I want to learn assembly" and start with the first video tutorial they find that has "assembly" in the title, without considering whether it matches the ISA / OS / toolchain / hardware that would actually interest them the most.

Thank you all for the suggestions! adding -static to the second command solved the problem.

Please mark your question as solved and select your own answer.
